# what word means to hint at something bad or negative

Tags: meaning, verbs

I need to know the word that has the meaning "to hint at something bad or negative" because my friend said to find the word for it. I've tried to go on Google but it hasn't worked, so I need your help please.

Comment: Hi amina. We're gonna need some context. Could you maybe give us an example situation. Or better yet, an example sentence with a blank where you need the word.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps ***casting aspersions*** is what you are looking for.

Dropping a negative hint about someone without making an outright criticism would amount to that.

*Were you casting aspersions in my direction, by any chance?*

Comment: Good one, +1. For a more modern bent: *throwing shade*.

Answer (score 3):

*[Foreshadow](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/foreshadow)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   Be a warning or indication of (a future event):
>
> *<sub>ODO</sub>*

From *[Race on the QT](https://books.google.com/books?id=sZSCBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA16&dq=foreshadow&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CE93Va3cJsGwsATPz4LQDg&ved=0CDIQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=foreshadow&f=false)* by Adilifu Nama:

> Although Cabot's “racial” comment is delivered as an absent-minded
>   throwaway line, it ***foreshadows*** a litany of racial name-calling
>   throughout the rest of the film that explicitly degrades African
>   Americans.
>
> ***Emphasis*** added

Answer (score 2):

When I want to say someone is *hinting at something insulting or unpleasant*, I usually  use the word ***insinuate***.

Oxford Dictionaries Online (ODO):

> *[insinuate](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/insinuate)*: suggest or hint (something bad or reprehensible) in an indirect and unpleasant way.
>
> *he was insinuating that she had slept her way to the top*

MacMillan:

> *[insinuate](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/insinuate)*: to say something unpleasant in an indirect way
>
> *He even went as far as insinuating that Roger was a liar.*

Merriam-Webster (MW):

> *[insinuate](http://i.word.com/idictionary/insinuate)*: to say (something, especially something bad or insulting) in an indirect way

Answer (score 2):

*[Portend](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/portend)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   Be a sign or warning that (something, especially
>   something momentous or calamitous) is likely to happen:

From *[Atlas of Great Comets](https://books.google.com/books?id=VEF5BgAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&dq=%22portend%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=HE13VaWzFIeJsQSLlb2wBA&ved=0CDUQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=%22portend%22&f=false)* by Ronald Stoyan:

> Almost in the centre of it, above the Prechistenka Boulevard,
>   surrounded and sprinkled on all sides by stars but distinguished from
>   them all by its nearness to the earth, its white light, and its long
>   uplifted tail, shone the enormous and brilliant comet of 1812 – the
>   comet which was said to ***portend*** all kinds of woes and the end of
>   the world.”
>
> ***Emphasis*** added

Answer (score 1):

You could try

- to intimate that. . . 
  (not IN•ta•mut; IN•ta•mayt)

Although strictly speaking, this means simply to make known, the usual connotation is to hint at some presumably unpleasant consequence, or to make a roundabout derogatory remark. See, for example, the samples shown here, http://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/intimate, under "VERB".

Answer (score 0):

Your question as it stands brings me to the word ***[ominous](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ominous)***:

> Giving the worrying impression that something bad is going to happen; threateningly inauspicious:
>
> "there were ominous dark clouds gathering overhead"

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for ***to caution***. More urgently, one might ***warn*** or ***forewarn*** a person of something negative up ahead; most urgently (and the least subtly), one would ***alert*** someone of impending trouble.